# Storing HTML markup in a PHP string

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an email automation using PHP. Originally I had this:

```
function send_email($email) {
    $message = "Hello! Here is an email message";
    mail($email, "Subject Line", $message, "from: email@ouremail.co.uk");
}
```

However I want to make the message emailed much longer and include some HTML markup (simple h1's and p tags).

I'm new to PHP but have been OK finding information on how to output PHP in HTML, but not how to include HTML within a PHP variable. I need to be able to store the markup inside `$message`.

And another thing I can't get my head around. If I want to write words like `don't` in my HTML, then I can't use a "`'`" to open and close. I must use `"` instead. Is this correct?

ETA: Is there anyway to instead send an entire HTML file via this function? So I could create a nice looking template for the email instead and just send that .html file via email.

Comment: See http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to set your mail headers to support HTML.

As far as PHP goes, it's pretty much standard:

```
$message = "<div>Hello! Here is an <span class='myClass'>email</span> message</div>";
```

Read also about heredoc and nowdoc here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. They will be *very* helpful when writing long multiline messages. For example:

```
$message = <<<EOT
Hello!
Here is an <span class='myClass'>email</span> message!
EOT;
```

For quotes you need to use backslash for escaping, like this:

```
$message = "Hello, \"people\"! Don't you know this is an email message";
```

or

```
$message = 'Hello, "people"! Don\'t you know this is an email message';
```

Note that using double quotes parses the PHP variables inside the string:

```
$x = 'world';
$message = "Hello $x"; // outputs: Hello world
$message = 'Hello $x'; // outputs: Hello $x
```

You might also want to consider encoding/decoding HTML entities within a PHP string. This is a good start: http://php.net/htmlentities

About templating, you can always create a function or an include file which would contain the template message, and then just decorate it with custom data for each message. There are many ways to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, I have done this now. However the HTML markup I have is very long. How do I call the file in? Can I do `$message = email.html` and put `require email.html` at the top of my functions file?

Comment: No problem. Hm, the fastest way would probably be to assign the contents of your template to a variable. Try converting the email.html into email.php and use the heredoc method I've shown you to assign the full html into a variable, and then just require it (just like you suggested) in your main file. If not, you can use `file_get_contents` to load it into a variable using only a single PHP file.